# URL not working on FallbackResource in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to redirect user to external website using `FallbackResource`

when i am trying `FallbackResource https://www.example.com` i am getting `500 error`.

But when i do something like `FallbackResource /fallback.php`everything is fine.

How to make user redirect using FallbackResource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an external URL with `FallbackResource`. You can't *externally redirect* the request using `FallbackResource`. As [the docs state](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource), this should be a ***local-url***.

If you want to do this then use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This gives you more control that `FallbackResource`. You can set the 3xx status and you can choose to redirect requests that would otherwise map to a directory, which `FallbackResource` would not (and often doesn't return a meaningful response for the user anyway).

The above 302 redirects any request, other than the document root (denoted by the regex `.`) and that doesn't map to a file or directory to `https://www.example.com/`.

Comment: `FallbackResource` redirect all url which does not exists in the website same like `ErrorDocument`. Do your code function same as `FallbackResource` with redirect to external website?

Comment: @Mèrebaiseur Yes. `FallbackResource` was introduced later as an alternative to using mod_rewrite to implement a front-controller pattern. As noted above, mod_rewrite allows you to do the same (and more). (If you externally redirect the request then this isn't a front-controller pattern so it's logical that `FallbackResource` does not permit this.)